# anti join pandas data frames at different levels in python

Tags: python, pandas, anti-join

I am having two pandas data frames say df1 and df2.
 df1 has 6 variables and df2 has 5 variables.
 and first variable in both the data frames are in string format and reaming are in int format.

i want to identify the  mismatched records in both data frames by using first 3 
 columns of both data frames  and have to exclude them from df1 dataframe.

for that i tried the following code but it throws Nan values for me, if i drop the 
 Nan values then required data will be deleted.

***input data:-***

```
**df1:-**                 **df2:-**  

x1   x2 x3 x4 x5 x6      x1  x2 x3 x4 x5
SM   1  1  2  3  3       RK  2  4  3  4  
RK   2  2  3  4  5       SM  1  1  3  3  
NBR  1  2  2  5  6       NB  1  2  3  2
CBK  2  5  6  7  8       VSB 5  6  3  2  
VSB  5  6  4  2  1       CB  2  6  4  1
SB   6  2  3  2  1       SB  6  2  4  1
```

***expected_out_put:-***

```
x1  x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
RK  2  2  3  4  5
CBK 2  5  6  7  8
NBR 1  2  2  5  6
```

***syntax:-***

```
data_out=df1[~df1['x1','x2','x3'].isin(df2['x1','x2','x3'])]
data_out=data_out.dropna()
```

please anyone can help me to tackle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Performing an inner merge will keep only the records in `df1` that match with a record in `df2`: `df1.merge(df2, on=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], how='inner')`. This will exclude anything mismatched, and also anything in `df1` that is not in `df2`. Not sure if that last condition counts as a 'mismatch`

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some sample data, as well as an example of the desired output. Currently, it is not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: ok, i will add.

Comment: if your result df has na in all the rows , dropna will drop all rows which has na anywhere in any column, dropna(how='all') should be used where you want to drop the rows where all values are na in every column. However, if you post a sample df and the expected df , it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join first, get columns names of added columns from `df2` and filter out all non `NaN`s rows by them:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
print (df)
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x4_  x5_
0   SM   1   1   2   3   3  3.0  3.0
1   RK   2   2   3   4   5  NaN  NaN
2   NB   1   2   2   5   6  3.0  2.0
3   CB   2   5   6   7   8  NaN  NaN
4  VSB   5   6   4   2   1  3.0  2.0
5   SB   6   2   3   2   1  4.0  1.0

cols = df.columns.difference(df1.columns)
print (cols)
Index(['x4_', 'x5_'], dtype='object')

df = df.loc[df[cols].isnull().all(axis=1), df1.columns.tolist()]
print (df)
   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
1  RK   2   2   3   4   5
3  CB   2   5   6   7   8
```

EDIT:

With your sample data I get:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
print (df)
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x4_  x5_
0   SM   1   1   2   3   3  3.0  3.0
1   RK   2   2   3   4   5  NaN  NaN
2  NBR   1   2   2   5   6  NaN  NaN
3  CBK   2   5   6   7   8  NaN  NaN
4  VSB   5   6   4   2   1  3.0  2.0
5   SB   6   2   3   2   1  4.0  1.0

cols = df.columns.difference(df1.columns)
print (cols)
Index(['x4_', 'x5_'], dtype='object')

df = df.loc[df[cols].isnull().all(axis=1), df1.columns.tolist()].x1.tolist()
print (df)
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
1   RK   2   2   3   4   5
2  NBR   1   2   2   5   6
3  CBK   2   5   6   7   8
```

Comment: it is giving expected results if both data frame records are in same order. if we change the order of the records in a data frame it won't give the expected result.can you check it once?

Comment: @neeraja  - Do you think swap `SM` and `CB` rows? I think it should working nice.

Comment: only in df2 not in df1.

Comment: @neeraja - Can you edit question with sample which not working? Tjhanks.

Comment: @neeraja - Why `NBR` and `CBK` are swapped? Ordering is `['RK', 'NBR', 'CBK']` in sample data in `df1`, or not?

Comment: output ordering is not an issue, but i want expected records in output data frame.

Comment: @neeraja - Please check edited answer, for me it working nice.

Comment: Okay I will check it one more time.Thanks.

Comment: i tried the following code, it is working as expected.                                         
by=['x1','x2','x3']
out=df1[~df1[by].apply(tuple,1).isin(df2[by].apply(tuple,1))].reset_index()

Comment: @neeraja - So `out=df1[~df1[by].apply(tuple,1).isin(df2[by].apply(tuple,1))].reset_index()` working and my code not?

Comment: it is also working fine, but in different situations that is not giving me the desired output.Thanks.